# can't launch intellij ubunty from icon

Tags: intellij-idea

I have problems with launch IntelliJ from the icon- it doesn't launch although, I can open it only when I'm using the following command:
/intellij-idea-ultimate/181/bin/idea.sh

after that i have some informations like this :

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2019-11-18 19:44:55,311 [   6362]   WARN - s.impl.EditorColorsManagerImpl - Cannot find scheme: 

VibrantInk from plugin: com.intellij.database 
2019-11-18 19:44:55,311 [   6362]   WARN - s.impl.EditorColorsManagerImpl - Cannot find scheme: WarmNeon from plugin: com.intellij.database 
2019-11-18 19:44:55,311 [   6362]   WARN - s.impl.EditorColorsManagerImpl - Cannot find scheme: High сontrast from plugin: com.intellij.database 
2019-11-18 19:45:04,669 [  15720]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinDefaultHighlightingSettingsProvider 
2019-11-18 19:45:10,206 [  21257]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
```

Comment: Try reinstalling from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html. Move/rename [IDE folders](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) to start over.

Comment: If you are new to linux try installing it through the Ubuntu Software app. It will manage your installation adding shortcuts properly

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by installing JetBrain Tools, now when i want to open Intellij i choose it from Toolbox